# Exporting cpython AST symbols on Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, cpython

I'm writing a C application that makes use of Python's AST API to transform Python code expressions before emitting bytecode. I've been a longtime POSIX developer (currently OS X), but I wish learn how to port my projects to Windows as well.

I'm using the static libraries (.lib) generated by `build.bat` in Python's `PCBuild` directory. The trouble with these libraries is they somehow skip over the symbols in `Python/Python-ast.c` as well as `Python/asdl.c`. I need these APIs for their AST constructors, but I'm not sure how to get Visual Studio to export them.

Do I need to add `__declspec(dllexport)` for static libraries?

EDIT: I do not have this problem with static libraries generated on POSIX platforms

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out

I was using VS 2013 while Python's build system was designed for VS 2010.

I ended up retargeting everything for 2013 (including a small modification to the `tix` makefile) and it compiled with all non-static symbols (AST and all) as expected.

Python.org's official pre-built Windows libraries still seem to omit the AST symbols. I don't mind building Python from source myself, but I think the official builds should package the whole shebang.